# Mysql client using reverse DNS instead of IPv4 address when connecting to remote db

Tags: mysql, reverse-dns

I have a server on Hetzner. When using the MySQL client to connect to a remote db from cli of that server, it returns the error:

> Access denied for user 'user'@'static.x.x.x.x.clients.your-server.de' (using password: YES)

Assuming my server ip x.y.z.t, There is a grant for user@x.y.z.t  on remote db.

If mysql client takes my host as x.y.z.t rather than static.x.x.x.x.clients.your-server.de, I am sure I can easily connect to remote db.

I run the code `sudo resolvectl flush-caches` on my server , but did not work.

My server is `Linux myserver 5.15.0-67-generic  Ubuntu   x86_64 GNU/Linux`

**UPDATE** : I have solved this problem by adding `skip-name-resolve`
to the remote mysql conf file. With this configuration, mysql server will not try to resolve ip of connecting users